# FadeIn and FadeOut when page scroll

Tags: jquery

I create some div, where i put my social link. I want do when user scroll page more then > 100, it div fade in, and when user come back to < 100, fadeOut. How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - demo: https://so.lucafilosofi.com/fadein-and-fadeout-when-page-scroll/

```
<style type="text/css">
    #social-icons-wrapper {
    /* CUSTOM PROPERTIES */
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px; 
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    height:32px;
    /* REQUIRED PROPERTIES */
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
}
</style>

<div id="social-icons-wrapper"><!-- SOCIAL ICONS HERE --></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 $(function () {
     $(window).scroll(function () {
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
             $('#social-icons-wrapper').stop().fadeIn(200);
         } else {
             $('#social-icons-wrapper').stop().fadeOut(200);
         }
     });
 });
//]]> 
</script>
```